# SPA Cors .net core with react typescript

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, typescript, cors

I have an SPA with React Typescript and .Net core 2.1.
The application has been deployed to an webapp in Azure.
The problem occurs after I have done a refresh on the web application, but not on the first login.
All my request goes through as well.

[image]

I have enabled Cors on the server side and also implemented cors in the backend.

[image]

I think the issue occurs inside registerServiceWorker.ts but not sure how to fix it.
I have not done any configurations in this file so it's only the default values.
Hope someone can point me in the right directions.

Backend .net core:

```
            public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // cors
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
                    builder =>
                    {
                        builder
                        .AllowAnyOrigin()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .AllowCredentials();
                    });
            });
    }
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // global policy
            app.UseCors("AllowAll");
    }

 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [EnableCors("AllowAll")]
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: If I read the error correctly, the blocked request goes to login.windows.net so CORS setting in your own app will not have any effect.

Comment: But it should not send a request to login.windows.net because I'm already authenticated

Comment: Based on the information you provided in your question, it's not possible to understand why it's redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Found out why it was redirecting.
Had some issues with refreshing the token from server that did not work correctly.

Comment: How you solved this issue? For me is the same. Thank you.